# How to extract a rectangle of text from a file in CLI?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

**Huge note: I AM NOT TALKING ABOUT TEXT EDITORS!**

I need to extract (stdout is OK) a rectangle of text from a text file.
A rectangle should be the text between lines l1 and l2 and columns c1 and c2.

I can already do this with a head, tail and cut in a nice pipe and am wondering whether there is a tool that can do it "all at once"(tm).

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You could use sed, it is very flexible.
For instance, to print lines 2 to 5, and 4 columns starting at column 3:

```
sed -n '2,5 s/^.\{3\}\(.\{1,4\}\).*$/\1/p'
```

- `-n` means do not print the line if no match
- `2,5` means only for lines 2 to 5
- `s/1/2/p` means substitute 1 by 2 and print it
- `^.\{3\}`  match at start of line (^) any character exactly 3 times
- `\( \)`  selects what we will output using `\1` in replace part
- `.\{1,4\}` select any character once up to 4 occurences
- `.*$`      match any character up to the end of line

All together, this will do what you want.

EDIT:
The previous solution is missing lines with less than 4 characters.
A better solution is:

```
sed -n '2,5 s/^.\{0,3\}\(.\{0,4\}\).*$/\1/p'
```

This one will put empty line if the line is less than needed characters, by allowing 0 columns before output, and 0 columns in output.